# How would you build one Select stored procedure to handle any request from a table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to build a single select stored procedure for SQL 2005 that is universal for any select query on that table.

```
**Columns**
LocationServiceID
LocationID
LocationServiceTypeID
ServiceName
ServiceCode
FlagActive
```

For this table I may need to select by LocationServiceID, or LocationID, or LocationServiceTypeID or ServiceName or a combination of the above.

I'd rather not have a separate stored procedure for each of them.

I assume the best way to do it would be to build the 'WHERE' statement on NOT NULL. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM LocationServiceType WHERE

  IF @LocationID IS NOT NULL (LocationID = @LocationID)
  IF @LocationServiceID IS NOT NULL (LocationServiceID = @LocationServiceID)
  IF @LocationServiceTypeID IS NOT NULL (LocationServiceTypeID = @LocationServiceTypeID)
  IF @ServiceName IS NOT NULL (ServiceName = @ServiceName)
  IF @ServiceCode IS NOT NULL (ServiceCode = @ServiceCode)
  IF @FlagActive IS NOT NULL (FlagActive = @FlagActive)
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: you don't use _IF_ the _WHERE_ signifies that they are conditions

Comment: Yes, I do know this is not proper syntax. It was just the easiest way of giving a visual representation for what I wanted. 

As for 'why', because I want to make it simpler. Yes the stored procedure will be more complicated but it will simplify maintenance down the road. That, and once I know how, I can do this for other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM LocationServiceType
WHERE LocationServiceID = ISNULL(@LocationServiceID,LocationServiceID)
  AND LocationID = ISNULL(@LocationID,LocationID)
  AND LocationServiceTypeID = ISNULL(@LocationServiceTypeID,LocationServiceTypeID)
  AND ServiceName = ISNULL(@ServiceName,ServiceName)
  AND ServiceCode = ISNULL(@ServiceCode,ServiceCode)
  AND FlagActive = ISNULL(@FlagActive,FlagActive)
```

If a null value is sent in it will cancel out that line of the where clause, otherwise it will return rows that match the value sent in.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. For what I'm doing this gets the job done and since it's a console app I'm not worried about SQL Injection or performance.

Answer (score 3):

here is the most extensive article I've ever seen on the subject:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

here is an outline of the article:

> ```
>  Introduction
>       The Case Study: Searching Orders
>       The Northgale Database
>    Dynamic SQL
>       Introduction
>       Using sp_executesql
>       Using the CLR
>       Using EXEC()
>       When Caching Is Not Really What You Want
>    Static SQL
>       Introduction
>       x = @x OR @x IS NULL
>       Using IF statements
>       Umachandar's Bag of Tricks
>       Using Temp Tables
>       x = @x AND @x IS NOT NULL
>       Handling Complex Conditions
>    Hybrid Solutions – Using both Static and Dynamic SQL
>       Using Views
>       Using Inline Table Functions
>    Conclusion
>    Feedback and Acknowledgements
>    Revision History
> ```

Comment: +1 Erland should be in the FAQs for this place, or they should add some logic to detect and auto-link...

Comment: This is a great article. It's something I'll have to reread a few times and play around with.

Comment: the article really shows that there is no "correct way", that it always depends on MANY factors

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code will not work. It should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationServiceType WHERE
(@LocationID IS NULL OR (LocationID = @LocationID)
... -- all other fields here
```

This is totally valid and known as 'all-in-one query'. But from a performance point of view this is not a perfect solution as soon as you don't allow SQL Server to select optimal plan. You can see more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bartd/archive/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isn-t-the-best-solution-the-all-in-one-search-query.aspx).

Bottom line: if your top priority is 'single SP', then use this approach. In case you care about the performance, look for a different solution.

Comment: @WACM161, read the article linked in my answer, it covers this solution and the possible performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done is is set the incoming parameters to null if should be ignored in query
then check variable for null first, so if variable is null condition short circuits and filter is not applied.  If variable has value then 'or' causes filter to be used.  Has worked for me so far.

```
SET @LocationID = NULLIF(@LocationID, 0)
SET @LocationServiceID = NULLIF(@LocationServiceID, 0)
SET @LocationServiceTypeID = NULLIF(@LocationServiceTypeID, 0)


    SELECT * FROM LocationServiceType WHERE

      (@LocationID IS NULL OR LocationID = @LocationID)
     AND (@LocationServiceID IS NULL OR LocationServiceID = @LocationServiceID)
     AND (@LocationServiceTypeID IS NULL OR @LocationServiceTypeID = @LocationServiceTypeID)
```

etc...